# Спуфинг телефонного номера

Tags: безопасность, mobile

Я начинающий специались в области ИБ и от руководства пришла задача предотвратить спуфинг номеров компании, покопавшись и интернете нашел много интересного, но к сожалению не совсем понятную информацию, хотелось бы  почитать более четко сформулированную информацию, как говориться "все по полочкам". Интересно как выполняется спуфинг, как от него защититься и почему так происходит, единственное, что пока мне понятно, это некая уязвимость в протоколе ss7.

Comment: Какой смысл вы вкладываете в транскрипцию слова spoofing в данном употреблении?

Comment: Подмена источника отсылки и как следствие маскировка под легальный источнык.